# Interfaces using the same internal virtual switch in Hyper-V don't ping

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

I have Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7 on virtual machines (HyperV). Win7 has 2 internal interfaces (Local Area Connection 4 and 5), the same situation is on Server 2008. 
All interfaces are using one, the same internal virtual switch.

I thought that they are all in the same subnet now and should ping each other, but the only machines that can communicate are interface 5 (Win7) with interface 4 from Server.

How can I connect them all?  Do I understand this interfaces and virtual switches properly?

When I do ping command I get: Reply from ...Server IP adress.. Destination host unreachable.

Virtual switch has static IP adress 192.168.1.1, when I set default Gateway on my interfaces I get error: warning- Multiple default gateways are intended to provide redundancy to a single networ. They will not function properly when the gateways are on two seperate, disjoint networks.

Answer (score 0):

Your internal interfaces are suppose to have one configured for the current network your on and the other interface can be bridged to have the virtual network established. One interface will have the same Local Area network as the machine your using to run the virtual machines which allows your virtual machines to use the network. Also make sure you name your interfaces to keep them distinguished from each other, for example "NAT" and the other "Internalnet" hope this helps.